# iOS 11 Beta 2 / Xcode Beta 3 AutoLayout Issue

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, ios-autolayout, ios11

I am using Autolayout to format a UITableViewCell in storyboard. I have experience using Autolayout and was able to easily setup rules for each item in the cell. It looks great in Storyboard (even when I toggle between different screen sizes), however, when I run the app on a device, all of the items are bunched up in the top left corner of the cell, overlapping each other.

Is there a known error in Autolayout for iOS 11 or am I doing something totally wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: At a minimum, you will need to add images of the storyboard, all the constraints and an image of the cell not displaying correctly. Have you also checked the constraints using the view debugger and checked the output window for Autolayout constraint issues?

Comment: @RoboticCat I will work on getting screenshots. I looked in view debugger and the items are incorrectly positioned. All of the items seem to have X and Y coords of (0,0) even though they have values for leading space and trailing space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I migrated to iOS 11 recently and faced the same issue for a custom cell. Tried too many things but failed. Finally I put below code in my custom cell and it worked for me.

```
self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
```

Hopefully it works for you or any new migrant to iOS 11.